# can I use "not" " ! " on ternary?

Tags: java

it might be a stupid question but can I use "!" on a ternary?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Detyra1{
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Write a positive or negative number: ");
        int x = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.print(x + " is a " + (x>=0 ? "Positive":"Negative")+" number ");
    }   
}
```

Like when the user types a negative number the output to show " Positive"

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes you can. What error did you find in the above code?

Comment: The above code works fine

Comment: Yes the code above works fine because theres not any "!" there.

Comment: Why not "not"? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The semantics is:

```
(boolean ? value1 : value2)
```

Examples:

```
(x >= 0 ? "Positive":"Negative")
(!(x < 0) ? "Positive":"Negative")
```

On the other hand, I would rather pick:

```
(!( x < 0 ) ? "Non-negative":"Negative")+" number ")
```

If you got an error, it might have been caused by the fact of operator precedence. `!x<0` would be *negation of x smaller than 0* which obviously don't make sense.

Comment: The second one doesn't work, should be `(!(x < 0) ? "Positive" : "Negative")`. Otherwise you'll get that `!` is undefined for `int`.

Comment: I think I applied my answer too early. I posted my edit at the same time you commented.

Comment: Why `!( x<0 )` and not the existing one? any reasons to pick that?

Comment: @nullpointer I assume the OP wants to use it and according to *Clean code* I wanted to bold that integers don't divide for positive and negative, but non-negative and negative (or positive and non-positive)

Answer (score 1):

Just switch both values instead of trying to use `!` :

`boolean ? value2 : value1`

is equivalent to :

`!boolean ? value1 : value2`,

and easier to read.

Here's an example with 4 equivalent expressions :

```
int x = 2;
System.out.println(x >= 0 ? "Positive" : "Negative");    // "Positive"
System.out.println(!(x >= 0) ? "Negative" : "Positive"); // "Positive"
System.out.println(x < 0 ? "Negative" : "Positive");     // "Positive"
System.out.println(!(x < 0) ? "Positive" : "Negative");  // "Positive"
```

All 4 will return `"Positive"` for `x==0`. If you want to return `"Unsigned"` in this case :

```
System.out.println(x == 0 ? "Unsigned" : (x > 0 ? "Positive" : "Negative"))
```

Comment: what if x is 0?

Comment: All 4 returns "Positive" for `x==0`, which is probably the least surprising result. If you want to return "Unsigned", you'll need 2 ternary operators.

Comment: @xenteros : Why did you ask?

Comment: I find this a main problem in the question. Simply that

Answer (score -2):

I got it . I just need to put "(" ")" on the right place / Thank you guys ,The full code after getting answers

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Detyra1{
public static void main (String [] args){
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Write a positive or negative number: ");
int x = sc.nextInt();

System.out.print(x + " is a " + (!(x >= 0) ? "Positive":"Negative")+" number ");


}


    }
```

Comment: Instead of posting another answer, just accept existing one.

Comment: I didn't say you guys didnt help me. Because of you guys I got how I should do it . I'm just posting the full code if anyone is wondering how it will look. Should I do an upvote or anything I dont know how thing go here . Sorry